What methods exist for partitioning a multi-terabyte table on Standard Edition without hours of down time?
Much of what I find online about partitioning large tables is very old. Databases are larger now and the old methods rarely account for the constraints of Standard Edition (partitioning was Enterprise only until 2016). This question exists to find modern methods of partitioning large tables on Standard Edition.
I have the following constraints. What methods exist for satisfying them on Standard Edition?

2 TB table. To keep things simple, assume that it has one ascending primary key and no other indexes/constraints/triggers.
Must be partitioned
The end of the table is hot. The rest is not.
Standard Edition, so RAM and online operations are limited
SQL Server 2022
No data loss allowed
Minimal down time allowed. 20 minutes at most. This likely rules out partitioning the table in place.
Optimistic locking of any kind is not enabled
This process can be done slowly, e.g. over weeks.


"The end of the table is hot. The rest is not." Would moving that hot end of the table take more than the 20min downtime allowed? Is the cold part of the table modified at all?

@Ronaldo Let's assume that the answer to both of your questions is "no". I'm interested to see where you're going with this. I'm getting the impression that you have hit a good idea.

I apologize for creating expectations about my idea. I could swear I had read all the answers before posting the comment, but I just noticed @teaboy has suggested the method I was about to propose: create a new partitioned table, migrate the old data first, use the 20min downtime to migrate the hot end and rename the table. Is there a problem with that method?

@Ronaldo I expect the copying of a multi-terabyte table to be painful, particularly on the transaction log.

Assuming that you are proposing horizontal partitioning, many tables, each with the same columns and some of the data. Given the restrictions listed, I suggest creating the new partitioned table with a different name, then, over a period of time, gradually copy the data from the current table into the new table. Set up a job to move small batches of data in the background. When done, use your 20 minutes to rename the old table to something else, rename the new table to the active table name and double check that the last work is up to date. Remember to check the permissions are correctly set on the new table, after renaming. After a backup and a day or two working without issues, you can drop the old table.


SQL Server 2022 standard version is powerful enough to support such  scale of db, unless the table is wide. What should be concerned is IO performence, before impliment partitioned table, you'd better make a better storage plan, such as deploying files into mutiple disks or using RAID as a simple way to use mutiple disks, or use SSD to store hot data.

Since converting a large table to a partitioned table might use a lot of memory resource to sort and concurrently operate on the data, tempdb will be used in this process, optimaizing tempdb is also required.

The best way to determine if a method satisfies your constraints is to build a test environment.

If convert to a partitioned table directly is not suitable for the constraints after testing, I think maybe you try to use Partitioned View as a transition process. The precondition of using this method is that the "cold" data should not be updated or deleted, and there is clear boundary that can identify cold data, and you have ability to modify a few code of applications that depend on this table.

a. Create a table to contain cold data, leave hot data in original table. Create a Partitioned View to return data from both table.

b. Modify code to use Partitioned View to query data, and insert/update/delete directly in the original table. Because there are many limites on updating Partitioned View, so you have to do this, and it's temporery, should backup origin code.

c. Then move data from original table to cold table by a slow batch loop untill all cold data has been moved. This step make sure all data is online and prepare partition data by use less resources.

d. After this, convert original table to partitioned table, This step is most expensive, but its scale will be much smaller now, so this step    should be faster and cost less resources.

e. Then move data from cold table to the partitioned table with a slow batch loop untill all cold data has been moved back.

f. At last, restore code to normal and remove Partitioned View.




Update:
Find a way which need not modify the code of applications - using trigger view.

In step b., you can create a INSTEAD OF TRIGGER on the Partitioned View to insert/update/delete the original table. So that need not modify code of applications which depends on the table. What you should do is 1. Offline the server; 2. modify the name of original table; 3. Name the Partitioned View to the original name of the table; 4. Create the INSTEAD OF TRIGGER on the view. 5. Online the server.

In step f., Need not restore code. Just Offline the server, remove the view, rename the partitioned table to origin name, online the server, it is done.



Find a way which need not modify the code of applications - using trigger view. @J-mini

I'm surprised that partitioned views are still remembered. They started out as a hack in the SQL Server 2000 days because we didn't have proper partitioning until SQL Server 2005. Not there is nothing wrong with them... It's just surprising!

In the face of such a challenge, we must try everything :D
